# Creacion de métodos en java

Tags: java

necesito por favor ayuda para crear la siguiente aplicación:
Escribir la aplicación Porcentajes, la cual acepta dos valores double del usuario desde el teclado, dejando estos en un par de variables. Luego se pasan estas variables a un método que muestra los dos valores y el valor del primer número como un porcentaje del segundo. Por ejemplo, si los números son 2.0 y 5.0 el método deberá mostrar algo como “2.0 es 40% de 5.0”. Después se llama a este método por segunda ocasión, invirtiendo los argumentos.

Lo que he intentado ha sido:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Porcentajes{ 
public static void main(String[] args]){ 
double primero; 
double segundo; 
Scanner primerValor = new Scanner(System.in); Scanner segundoValor = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(“ingrese dos valores: “); 
primero = primerValor.nextDouble();
segundo = segundoValor.nextDouble();
valores(primero,segundo);
System.out.println(valores(primero,segundo));
}
public static void valores(primero,segundo){
System.out.println(“los valores son: “ + primero + “y” + segundo);
System.out.println(primero + “es el “ + (primero/segundo)*100 + “% de “ + segundo);
}
}
```

Comment: que haz intentado? en que haz tenido fallos? la comunidad de SO en español con gusto te ayudará pero no te hara el trabajo por favor lee [ask] y de paso haz el [tour]

Comment: Gracias, es la primera vez que pregunto algo aqui.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. El anunciado es bastante fácil de realizar. Es con ese tipo de cosas sencillas con las que se aprende a programar, investigando cómo se crea un método, cómo se llama pasándole parámetros, cómo se hace un cálculo y se guarda en una variable, etc. No esperes a que lo hagamos por ti, investiga, haz un intento de código y si tienes alguna dificultad **con ese código en concreto, el cual has escrito después de haber investigado**, entonces sí se te ayudará con mucho gusto. Tu pregunta será muy probablemente cerrada, porque no se adapta a la finalidad del sitio. Saludos.

Comment: Ya lo he intentado y he visto tutoriales y leído sobre ello, lo que he hecho ha sido:

Comment: Ya he subido la mera en que lo intente

Answer (score 0):

Seria algo como esto, no tienes por que hacer dos veces la instancia a la clase Scanner con una vez esta bien ya que con esto podrás parsear tu entrada, el valor del porcentaje lo puedes sacar antes, y simplemente para mostrar lo que quieres haces una salida al ´System.out.print()´ faltaría agregar la lógica de como sacaras el porcentaje pero ya tienes la mayoría del trabajo hecho.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    double primero; 
    double segundo; 
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("ingrese El primer valor: "); 
    primero = entrada.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("ingrese El segundo valor: ");
    segundo = entrada.nextDouble();

    int porcentaje = (int) ((primero / segundo) * 100);


    System.out.println(primero + " es el " + porcentaje + "% de " + segundo);
}
```

Comment: Pero se supone que debo crear otro metodo

Answer (score 0):

Antes que nada, debes poner el tipo de dato a los parámetros del método:

```
public static void valores(primero,segundo)...
```

cambiar por:

```
public static void valores(double primero,double segundo)...
```

Solo puedes utilizar el System.out.println(), si el método que le estas enviando regresa un tipo de dato, es decir cambiar el void por String y crear una variable para concatenar los resultados y regresarlos:

public static **String** valores(double primero,double segundo)..

Si quieres mandar llamar otro método tu código quedaría de la siguiente forma, junto con todas las observaciones anteriores:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Porcentajes {


    public static String valores(double primero,double segundo){
        String resultado = "los valores son: " + primero + " y " + segundo+"\n";
        resultado += primero + " es el " + (primero/segundo)*100 + " % de " + segundo+"\n";
        return resultado;
    }

    public static String otrosValores(double segundo,double primero){
        String resultado = "los valores son: " + segundo + " y " + primero+"\n";
        resultado += segundo + " es el " + (segundo/primero)*100 + " % de " + primero+"\n";
        return resultado;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        double primero; 
        double segundo; 
        Scanner primerValor = new Scanner(System.in); 
        Scanner segundoValor = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("ingrese dos valores: "); 
        primero = primerValor.nextDouble();
        segundo = segundoValor.nextDouble();
        valores(primero,segundo);
        System.out.println(valores(primero,segundo));
        System.out.println(otrosValores(segundo,primero));
    }

}
```